# table row (<tr>) can't recieve pointer events, when table data pointer events are deactivated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple table with table data and want to make the table row clickable and do something on click.

Without any css the  elements are the event targets but i want to make only the table row the event target so what i did is the following:

```
td {
  pointer-events: none;
}

tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This worked when i did it with div's that cotains spans but with tr's and td's it doesnt, as the table row now **doesnt allow any pointer** events even if i add them.

Does anyone know a workaround for that?

Comment: *"This worked when i did it with div's that cotains spans..."* That would be surprising. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating both that and the problem with `tr`/`td`, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Your approach is flawed. Using event delegation properly will solve your problem.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the `td`s be the target? If you look the clicks on the `tr`, you'll get the clicks when they bubble to the `tr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> **none**
>
> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

So disallowing `pointer-events` on `td` elements means clicking the `td` (rather than margin around the `td` that's within the `tr`) won't work.

Instead, just hook `click` on the `tr` or even the `tbody` or `table`; example:

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Is it a click on a tr in this table?
  var tr = e.target.closest("tr");
  if (tr && this.contains(tr)) {
    // Yes, toggle highlight
    tr.classList.toggle("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*(The `contains` part there ensures that if the table you're doing this on is inside another table, clicks that aren't in a `tr` on *this* table don't get handled.)*

More:

- [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`Node.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)